# heroku rollback didn't update the HEAD remote branch, did it?

Tags: git, heroku, rollback

I incorrectly made a push to heroku and used heroku rollback to roll it back to a previous version.  That worked fine in that my heroku app is now serving the rolled back version.

But when a colleague who had pulled the "corrupted" push tried to checkout the "correct" version after the rollback, his git checkout from master branch is giving him the "corrupted" version and not the rolled back version.

Any idea why Heroku rolled back the application but not the master git repo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally you shouldn't be using Heroku to host your Git repo but:

The version that Heroku is running and the HEAD commit on the Git repo are two different things.  When you push, that tells the Heroku railguns to compile HEAD and deploy it.  When you rollback it tells the railguns to compile a slug for the previous commit.  It doesn't do anything to the Git repo.

Therefore, after a rollback, Heroku is running HEAD -1 whilst the Git repo is untouched.

Comment: Agreed. I tried `git pull heroku <branch>` after I did the rollback, and I got the same code as before.
After the rollback, how can the heroku HEAD be updated, so that I can pull that to local?

Answer (score 2):

1. Locate the number of the rollback version you are after by viewing previous releases in terminal. (The value after n indicates the number of entries you want to see. The last ~15 application edits show with "heroku releases")

   ```
   heroku releases -n 7
   ```
2. Terminal will show the last number of application versions/releases you requested.

   ```
   user@computer:~/dev/my-great-app$ heroku releases -n 7
   === my-great-app Releases
   v36  Rollback to v34            email@example.com  2016/12/01 04:49:01 (~ 3h ago)
   v35  Deploy 7234c83             email@example.com  2016/12/01 03:26:58 (~ 5h ago)
   v34  Deploy 1367a4f             email@example.com  2016/11/30 21:25:07 (~ 11h ago)
   v33  Set RAILS_ENV config vars  email@example.com  2016/11/30 13:12:18 (~ 22h ago)
   v32  Deploy 4536b70             email@example.com  2016/11/16 18:16:58
   v31  Deploy 731f37c             email@example.com  2016/10/23 04:33:18
   v30  Deploy 1fb79a6             email@example.com  2016/10/12 04:52:00
   ```
3. Pick the deployment you want to pull. (In this case I have chosen 1367a4f because v34 was the clean version of the application.)

   ```
   git pull heroku 1367a4f
   ```
4. You now have a copy of your application from a heroku rollback version. To save this copy, be certain to create a branch for it in your git environment. If you are dead new at this, you could, for peace of mind, copy the entire directory and stash it somewhere but this isn't necessary. (Please don't mark this answer down for suggesting a directory backup for those still fumbling a bit with git.)