# Heroku and Git are not updating, pushing, or pulling properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, github

I'm literally falling apart at the seams with angry, nervous laughter. Someone PLEASE help me...

Screenshots: https://medium.com/p/4ff0a5af7f53

1. Run `git status`, I am on working branch `Redesign` with nothing to commit and a clean working directory.
2. Run `rails server` and navigate to `localhost:3000`. Yay pretty website, let's just denote it with a variable ABC
3. Run `git push heroku Redesign:master`, it tells me everything is up to date
4. Navigate to the website... it shows me a website that's totally different, XYZ, from several months ago
5. Ok, so I'm going to humor this, I'm going to navigate to a new branch `Rollback` and run a `git pull` from Heroku
6. Now on this `Rollback` branch I'm going to run `rails server` expecting to see the XYZ old site that I just pulled from Heroku
7. False, I instead get ABC (and the Sublime code shows the code for ABC as well)

By the way running the push with `--force` does not help. When I run heroku releases there is no record of this push.

WHAT IS HAPPENING????????

Sorry if I seem desperate... I've been at this for 2 hours

Comment: Is code location and server location same?

Comment: yes they are the same

Comment: If you run [`heroku releases`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/releases#listing-release-history) do you see a release deploying the revision you expect?

Comment: No I don't... not even when I use --force

Comment: @james, so what *do* you see with `heroku releases`?

Comment: a list of the releases, but the last release was not the one that I pushed with a --force, and I don't know why..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this was dumb of me, @Chris I think you were going to stumble upon it. I had done a `heroku rollback` and didn't realize that when you rollback on Heroku, the git repo head commit doesn't change.

This is the thread that solved it: [heroku rollback didn't update the HEAD remote branch, did it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898286/heroku-rollback-didnt-update-the-head-remote-branch-did-it/9906227#9906227)

Answer (score 0):

```
git add .
git commit -a -m "Message"
```

Have you performed these before you try and push? You have to update your local git repo before sending to Heroku